# How to reformat a text file - awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a text file containing 3 columns:

> broke   banana    192
>   broke   apple    175
>   broke   avocado   20
>   fixed   banana    117
>   fixed   apple    89

I need the output below:

> > Issue,banana,apple,avocado
> >     broke,192,175,20
> >     fixed,117,90,0

I am new to this and have no idea how to get this result.

I appreciate any help,
Thanks

Comment: the fields don't even have a correspondence, you should improve this question..

Comment: I don't understand where from you got `fixed,117,90` in expected o/p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat file
broke banana 192
broke apple 175
fixed banana 117
fixed apple 89
```

I don't understand where from you got `fixed,117,90` in expected o/p

**Output**

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '{
      is_fr[$1,$2]=$3

      if(!($1 in i_tmp))issue[++i]=$1; 
      if(!($2 in f_tmp))fruit[++f]=$2;

      i_tmp[$1]; f_tmp[$2]
   }
END{
      printf ("%s","issue"); 
      for(i=1; i in fruit; i++)
           printf("%s%s",OFS,fruit[i]); 
      print ""; 
      for(i=1; i in issue; i++)
      { 
          printf("%s",issue[i]); 
          for(j=1; j  in fruit; j++)
          { 
               printf("%s%s",OFS,(issue[i],fruit[j]) in is_fr ? is_fr[issue[i],fruit[j]]:"")
          } 
          print ""   
      }
    }' file   

issue,banana,apple
broke,192,175
fixed,117,89
```

If order doesn't matter then you may try below [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '{
      issue[$1]; 
      fruit[$2]; 
      is_fr[$1,$2]=$3
   }
END{
      printf ("%s","issue"); 
      for(i in fruit)
           printf("%s%s",OFS,i); 
      print ""; 
      for(i in issue)
      { 
          printf("%s",i); 
          for(j in fruit)
          { 
               printf("%s%s",OFS,(i,j) in is_fr ? is_fr[i,j]:"")
          } 
          print ""   
      }   
   }' file
issue,apple,banana
fixed,89,117
broke,175,192
```

**For new input edited by OP**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat f
broke banana 192
broke apple 175
broke avocado 20
fixed banana 117
fixed apple 89 

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -v OFS=, '{
      is_fr[$1,$2]=$3

      if(!($1 in i_tmp))issue[++i]=$1; 
      if(!($2 in f_tmp))fruit[++f]=$2;

      i_tmp[$1]; f_tmp[$2]
   }
END{
      printf ("%s","issue"); 
      for(i=1; i in fruit; i++)
           printf("%s%s",OFS,fruit[i]); 
      print ""; 
      for(i=1; i in issue; i++)
      { 
          printf("%s",issue[i]); 
          for(j=1; j  in fruit; j++)
          { 
               printf("%s%s",OFS,(issue[i],fruit[j]) in is_fr ? is_fr[issue[i],fruit[j]]+0:0)
          } 
          print ""   
      }
    }' f
issue,banana,apple,avocado
broke,192,175,20
fixed,117,89,0
```

Comment: Hi Akshay, thanks for you help. I have another question.If a have a fruit that have empty value how can I add "zero" to it. For example, Avocado - fixed, 20 and for broke I need awk to add "0' to the column. Thanks again,

Comment: Hi Akshay, I think I am doing something wrong because is not adding 0 when i applied you suggestion.

Comment: Neither the output of `cat file` or the `awk` commands match the input and output shown in the OP. That said, the OP is extremely poorly written!

Comment: @CrisOlson: modify this line `printf("%s%s",OFS,(issue[i],fruit[j]) in is_fr ? is_fr[issue[i],fruit[j]]+0:0)`

Comment: Thanks Akshay, it's perfect! Sorry, for not explaining better in first place.

Comment: @Akshay Hegde, Sorry, I didn't notice he had edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{
    states[$1]
    fruits[$2]
    count[$1,$2] += $NF
}
END {
    printf "%s", "Issue"
    for (fruit in fruits) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, fruit
    }
    print ""

    for (state in states) {
        printf "%s", state
        for (fruit in fruits) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, count[state,fruit]+0
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Issue,apple,banana,avocado
fixed,89,117,0
broke,175,192,20
```